# fetch specific imap messages from specific folder

Tags: linux, email, imap, fetch

Situation:

On my Google Account I move all my done/read messages into a imap folder called "DONE". This folder contains emails from several years.

From time to time I move old emails from the remote folder DONE to my local mail-folder DONE, via Thunderbird (on OSX). This works.

Now I search a solution to automate this task. The solution should just fetch emails in the Google folder DONE, say from 2007-2010, to my local mail-folder and delete them on the Google server.

I did a research on fetchmail, imapsync and offlineimap, but couldn't figure out how to fetch only specific emails, the one from 2007-2010. fetching complete folders works, but this is not my intention.

**Any hints how I could solve my problem?**

Scripting (osx/linux/php/perl/etc) or a combination of tools would be an option as well for me, but I do not know where I should start.

cheers -- jerik

Comment: What [about to start here](http://www.voidynullness.net/blog/2013/07/25/gmail-email-with-python-via-imap/) or [with fetchmail](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92923/66388)?

Comment: @Hastur the python way is a good starting point. Thanks! The fetchmail option has the drawback, for my situation, that I would have to download all mails of the folder "DONE" and sort them. The folder itself has 2 GB, which would be quite a number to download every time...

Comment: ...I agree 2 GB are big enough. I read somewhere that with IMAP many client downloads only the __list of headers__. That can be fine for you. You can _parse_ the list and filter only the mail you want to download and after you can ask for a full download of only those ones. Googling here and there [I find a link](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-migrate-mailboxes-between-imap-servers-with-imapcopy) that points to a [java source](https://imapcopy.googlecode.com/files/imapCopy0.3.1.zip) maybe useful too.

Comment: @Hastur the python way seems to work for me. With a short ruby :) smoketest I could filter mails...